# Selecting dynamic Unix Epoch time with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, unix, amazon-redshift

I'm attempting to build a "last 30 days" dynamic SQL date filter for a user application. The date column is a unix epoch millisecond timestamp.

Previous iterations of the tool allowed the user to choose a date range, I'm now just changing it to choose the last 30.

The data is stored in Redshift, which does not support `from_unixtime`.

I have two challenges:

1. The data is stored in UTC and needs to be filtered with dates in EST (UTC -5).
2. "Choosing the last 30 days" means cutting off at midnight yesterday, and taking yesterday minus 29.

Previously, my code looked like this:

```
"datecol" >= DATEDIFF(millisecs, '1969-12-31 19:00:00', ''start date' 00:00:00') 
AND "datecol" <= DATEDIFF(millisecs, '1969-12-31 19:00:00', ''end date' 23:59:59')
```

The application would update the start and end dates as described by the user. This code is adjusted for the time difference.

How can I use `GETDATE()` and `DATEADD()` on a Unix timestamp, using the constraints of Redshift SQL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`extract('epoch' from ts)` gives you unix timestamps and you just add 5 hours to query UTC as if it is EST (if EST is UTC-5 then UTC is EST+5)

```
between extract('epoch' from ('<<date1>>' + interval '5 hour'))
and extract('epoch' from ('<<date2>>' + interval '29 hour' - interval '1 second'))
```

also, `from_unixtime` can be expressed in Redshift as the following:

```
select timestamp 'epoch' + unix_ts_column * interval '1 second'
```

a bit ugly but works just like that

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to write a **User Defined Function (UDF)** for your Redshift database using Python and the python standard `datetime` module. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/user-defined-functions.html

Follow the section titled `Creating a Scalar Python UDF`.

I don't quite understand your query or the context, but I think you can figure out how to get what you want using UDLs.

For example to get the milliseconds between two datetimes (one in UTC, one in EST)  you would write is like the following (not tested):

```
CREATE FUNCTION datediff_py(a datetime, b datetime)
  returns float
stable
as $$
    #python code goes here between the $$
    from datetime import datetime
    FMT = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' #dates like '2016-12-24 23:59:59'
    tdelta = datetime.strptime(a + " UTC", FMT + " %Z") - datetime.strptime(b + " EST", FMT + " %Z")
    return tdelta.total_seconds()*1000

$$ language plpythonu;
```

This computes the milliseconds between an SQL datetime `a` that is in `UTC` and `b` that is in `EST`. The `%Z` format is used for timezones. A usage would be:

`"datecol" >= datediff_py('1969-12-31 19:00:00', user_date)`

Of course Unix epoch is actually `'1970-01-01 00:00:00'`.

There are plenty of other date functions in the Python standard library [datetime module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#module-datetime), so you can write other UDLs if you need things like `GETDATE()` or `DATEADD()`, for exampling using `timedelta`